# Is it unusual to send questions that you may have after interview to the interviewer via email?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I have been interviewing since last few weeks & this is an unusual situation for me. First of all, it was a phone interview & in the beginning the interviewer asked me if I have any question(s) for him & the other interviewer. My reply was that I would definitely have some question(s) at the end.

Due to time constraint, they had to end the call exactly after half an hour & I couldn't get the chance to ask them any question(s).

Would it look good on my part if I reach out to the interviewer via the email and ask him the questions that I have? Also, how can I avoid these kind of situations in the future?

Comment: It seems like you could've easily avoided this situation by just asking when they asked if you had questions. This is possibly why they asked at the beginning instead of the end.

Comment: Asking the interviewer before the start seemed a little odd for me to be honest but I will definitely ask question(s) when they ask in future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it unusual to send questions that you may have after interview to the interviewer via email?

No, not at all -- it's common for candidates to think of questions they forgot to ask during the actual interview, and to follow up via phone or email.

> Would it look good on my part if I reach out to the interviewer via the email and ask him the questions that I have?

Yes. Having questions demonstrates your specific interest in the position and employer. Asking them later via email is fine.

> Also, how can I avoid these kind of situations in the future?

From your description, it sounds like the interview was ended abruptly, so I'm not sure this situation could have been avoided, or that you should have done anything differently.

Perhaps you could have asked if they had a time limit on the interview. If they let you know that up front, you may have been able to manage the time a little better, and get your questions in before the interview was over.

But most of the time, as you point out, the interviewer tries to leave sufficient time for questions. When I am interviewing candidates, and I'm running short on time, I cut my own questions short, to make sure I address any outstanding questions the candidate might have.

Comment: The interviewer generally guides the interview, so I'm not sure it's an issue of managing one's time better. They asked if OP had questions at the beginning - that would've been the best time to ask.

Comment: In 99% of the interviews I have had, interviewer generally gave me the opportunity to ask them questions at the end.

Comment: @mcknz, Also I am beginning to think that the interview was just a formality as they asked me a couple of technical / algorithm based questions as well.  Usually if you're planning on asking such questions you should ask the person to come in.

Comment: @user3777390 Some companies do a tech screen over the phone, and then follow up with an in-person interview. Asking questions via email is probably a good way to gauge their interest level as well.

Comment: @mcknz: does not matter. By the time he gets a reply he would probably already know if there will be another interview round. If there isn't any they won't really spend time answering questions

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is their problem not yours. They are supposed to give all the information needed so as to keep good candidates to go through their process. So it should not concern you.
At this point whatever you do does not really matter in the sense that if the interviewers approved you, you will get a call for the next step and you will get a chance to ask your questions. If they have rejected you you won't get any meaningful response anyway.
In case you decide to ask anyway (which as explained is of no benefit to you at this point) then send the email to the person that arranged the interview instead of the interviewers. Unless the interviewers told you it is fine if you contacted them.